# Is "use" in perl transitive?

Tags: perl, perl-module

```
package AA;

package BB;
use AA;

package CC;
use BB;
```

Do i have to put `use AA` in CC, or is that implicit ?

Comment: What happened when you tried to use stuff from `AA` in `CC`, assuming these are all in separate files?

Comment: i didnt try earlier, i was reviewing a large codebase and this question came to my mind. Thanks for ur replies !!

Answer (score 9):

You can [use](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#use-Module-VERSION-LIST) a module as long as it's been loaded before by something. This is why you can use objects created by other modules without knowing what object type they are. For example, you can use an [`HTTP::Response`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response) object you get back from an [`LWP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP) method, although you never loaded `HTTP::Response` yourself or realized it was that sort of object. However, the `use` only imports into the calling namespace, so those imports won't show up in other packages (even though you can still call them with the complete package specification).

You should `use` any module that your package wants to use directly. That is, `use` the modules for the objects that you directly create.

You also shouldn't rely on other packages to load modules for you. If someone changes those modules, you'll be stuck wondering why things broke. And, even then, you rely on module loading order to ensure that it all works out.

Answer (score 4):

[`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) does two things: Loads a module (as if by `require`) if it's not already loaded, and calls the module's `import` method. Not sure how loading a module or calling a method can can be transitive.

As for your second question, it depends,  primarily on whether AA has an `import` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
package AA;

package BB;
use AA;

package CC;
use BB;
```

is nearly the same as:

```
package CC;
use BB;
BEGIN{ require AA }
```

or

```
package CC;
use BB;
use AA ();
```

This is because [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) does two things. It loads the file with [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html), then calls the [`import`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/import.html) method on it.

So these are equivalent.

```
use Module qw'LIST';
```

```
BEGIN { require Module; Module->import( qw'LIST' ); }
```

---

You may have a problem if package `BB` doesn't need the `use AA;` line anymore, and it gets removed.

Answer (score -1):

It depends mainly on whether the modules involved are object-oriented ones or simple modules that use `Exporter` to make symbols available in the calling package.

What `use` does is first to `require` the given module and then call its `import` method.

`require` first checks `%INC` to see if the module has already been successfully loaded. If not, all the paths in `@INC` are searched for a matching module file and the first match is loaded with the equivalent of `do`.

The modules `import` method can do anything the author cares to write, but generally a module will subclass `Exporter` which provides an `import` method that, amongst other things, copies the symbols in the package's `@IMPORT` array to the calling package, making the symbols available there without fully-qualifying them with their package name.

In your example, if the modules subclass `Exporter`, symbols listed in `@BB::IMPORT` will be copied to the `CC` namespace and can be used from that package. Nothing has been imported from `AA` though, so subroutines from there can be called only by explicitly calling them as `AA::subroutine()` etc.

On the other hand, if the packages are object-oriented modules and `BB` subclasses `AA`, then normally there is no `import` method to call and the methods are accessed either through blessed variables or a class name (package name). Methods not defined in `BB` can be inherited from `AA` and Perl's implementation of the object-oriented inheritance system uses the package's `@ISA` array to determine where to continue searching for methods.

To summarize, if your module `BB` subclasses `Exporter` then you will also have to `use AA`. But if it is object-oriented and subclasses `AA` then all methods from both `BB` and `AA` are available to `CC` by just using `use BB`.